# Bind Events Understanding

Tags: javascript

Just going through some code on a vanilla JS to do list and I'm a bit confused about how this section is working.

The bit that blags my mind a bit is how the checkbox knows which list item is active. I understand we loop over the list items at the beginning and pass them as arguments but how does the checkbox know which one? Aren't we passing multiple list items to the 'taskListItem' argument here?

So when we click the checkbox I'm confused at how it knows which item to use.

Also is this a common way of binding things together? I'm trying to learn patterns so I can fully understand what's going on and can thus build in certain ways rather than just writing any old code.

If someone could break down what's going on here I'd be grateful!

Thanks

```
var bindTaskEvent = function (taskListItem, checkBoxEventHandler) {
    debugger

    console.log("Binding Events to Checkbox, Edit, Delete Buttons")

    // Select task's <li> children
    var checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
    var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

    // Bind checkBoxEventHandler to checkbox
    checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler;;

    // Bind editTask to Edit button
    editButton.onclick = editTask;

    // Bind deleteTask to Delete Button
    deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;
};

// TASK COMPLETED

var taskCompleted = function () {

    console.log("Running taskCompleted");

    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    completedTasks.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvent(listItem, taskIncomplete);
}

// TASK INCOMPLETE

var taskIncomplete = function () {

    console.log("Running taskIncomplete");

    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    incompleteTasks.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvent(listItem, taskCompleted);
}

//// WIRING OF THINGS...

// cycle over To Do List items
for (var i = 0; i < incompleteTasks.children.length; i++) {
    // bind events to <li>'s children
    bindTaskEvent(incompleteTasks.children[i], taskCompleted);
};

// cycle over Completed Items
for (var i = 0; i < completedTasks.children.length; i++) {
    // for each list item
    // bind event to <li> children (taskCompleted)
    bindTaskEvent(completedTasks.children[i], taskIncomplete);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 'taskListItem' gets multiple list items but the querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document. Therefore the first element is stored in the variable checkbox not the whole list.

Comment: But isn't 'queryselector' getting the first checkbox not the first 'taskListItem'?

I don't understand how the correct list item is selected.

Thanks!

Comment: whatever value  'taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");' returns is assigned to 'checkBox'. So 'querySelector()' gets the first css element which has the same property as "input[type=checkbox]" and assigns that element to the variable 'checkbox'